# C# list replaces items instead of adding them

Tags: c#, list

Here's the strangest problem I've ever seen. Consider this code I use to receive consecutive UDP datagrams (the sequence always ends with a datagram containing Base64-encoded message `FEND`):

```cs
var received = new List<string>(10);

while (received.LastOrDefault() != "FEND")
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[65535]; // 65535 is the maximum size of a UDP datagram
  client.Receive(buffer);

  string strBuffer = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
  strBuffer = strBuffer.TrimEnd('A'); // The buffer ends with zeros that are translated to "A"

  received.Add(strBuffer);

  Console.WriteLine();
}

received = received.Take(received.Count - 1).ToList();
```

`client` is a `Socket` field initialized with this code:

```cs
client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
```

`port` is specified by the client code (I'm writing a class library).

Here's the issue itself: the `received` list always *contains only one item*. I have added a `Console.WriteLine()` call into the end of `while` cycle and put there a breakpoint. When it hits, `strBuffer` contains a string of type `hoYfopfHUTDJf8erK...` (it's the expected value, and it is different in different iterations), and `received` contains a `List<string>` which **has its `Count` property equal to 1 in all iterations!** Its only item is the `strBuffer` value from the iteration I'm watching.

It seems like the `Add` call replaces the item in `received` instead of adding a new one. Is it an underlying bug or a stupid error?

*UPDATE:* in an [online C# compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/EAkoBVOdg) my code works fine.

Comment: `strBuffer.TrimEnd('A')` I think I just threw up in my mouth a little bit. What do you think happens if the actual string ends with `0xAA`?

Comment: @Blindy The actual buffer can't end with zeros.

Comment: You literally allocate and copy your received data around *five different times*. It's been a long time since I've been this negatively impressed by a small code snippet.

Comment: @Blindy I call the garbage collector after that (`GC.Collect()`).

Comment: It just keeps getting worse and worse. Instead of coding literally anything correctly, you throw in the one thing you should never ever ever call.

Comment: @Blindy It's at least logical to call the garbage collector when there's five to ten *huge* (65535 bytes) objects in the managed heap without references. Secondly, I may refer to my experience. I used garbage collector in my previous project (parent control application, WinForms) and in a project from 2019 (chatting application, WinForms), and both times it decreased the memory usage, as the Visual Studio diagnostics show. Without any visible minuses.

Comment: @Blindy I may also refer to the book I learned .NET by. Christian Nagel, Bill Evjen, Jay Glynn, Karli Watson, Morgan Skinner. Professional C# 2012 and .NET 4.5. A bit old, but main conceptions are the same. In its chapter 14 (memory management and pointers), there's an advice to call the garbage collector after dereferencing many object references.

Comment: Not interested in bad advice from ten years ago.

Comment: @Blindy And I'm not interested in your advice. I have my style, created, developed and tested when I became a developer, i. e. 8 years ago (though I joined Stack Overflow only two months ago), and I don't want to change it because it always worked for me well. I know the advantages of using GC, know the disadvantages and find it useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you really getting BASE64 text in UDP datagrams? Maybe you need [Encoding.GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=net-7.0#system-text-encoding-getstring(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) instead?
2. I think you could try something like this:

```cs
    var received = new List<string>(10);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65535]; // 65535 is the maximum size of a UDP datagram
    
    while (true)
    {
        var bytesReceived = client.Receive(buffer);
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
            break;
    
        string strBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
        if (strBuffer == "FEND")
            break;
    
        received.Add(strBuffer);
    
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm **absolutely** sure I get Base64-encoded datagrams. To encode them, I use `Convert.FromBase64String`, so to decode them I should use `Convert.ToBase64String`. Your code won't work because it tries to decode a Base64 byte array to a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Then you can just replace `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` with `Convert.ToBase64String(buffer, 0, bytesReceived)`.

Though it looks a bit strange to first convert some binary data (I guess original data is binary) into Base64 and then convert it to binary again instead of putting the original binary data into buffer directly. And on receiving side do the opposite (byte[] -> Base64 -> binary).

Comment: I just didn't provide enough context information. The original data (image data) is binary, but I want to add a message from the user before it. I convert the image data to Base64 string (a solution of how to convert image to string from Stack Overflow), add the message, convert back the result of concatenation and send. By the way, if I replace calls as you advise, I will get my original code (a bit modified, but with the same functionality).